# Removing a class from "untoggled" items and assigning it to selected item in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, toggle, accordion

I made a toggle component (Accordion to be exact)

I am mapping through an array of objects and listing them like:

```
{object.map((o) => (
   <Accordion key={o.id} title={o.question} className="item">
     <div className="text"> { o.answer } <div/>
   </Accordion>
))}
```

It renders something like this:

```
> Question 1
> Question 2
> Question 3
```

Now, every time I click a question, it toggles down to show the answer. All this works fine(I used hooks).

I want to be able to change the opacity of all the un toggled elements in this list when ONE of the questions is opened.

So if I open question 2, it becomes the "current item" and the opacity of question 2 and its answer should be 100% and all others(question1 an question3) should dim out or turn 50% opacity.. I am able to do it using :hover using css but that only works on hover.

Basically in theory, I should be able to select an item and remove the base class from all other items except the selected one. I don't know how to do that in reality. Help. 
I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

```
const Accordion = ({ title, children, opened = false }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(opened);
  const rotation = classnames('icon', {
    'rotate': show,
  });
  const content = classnames('contents', {
    'closed': !show,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(opened);
  }, [opened]);

  const toggle = useCallback(() => {
    setShow(!show);
  }, [show]);

  return (
      <div className='titleContainer' onClick={toggle}>
        <div className={rotations}>
          <i className='icon' />
        </div>
        <h5 className='title'>{title}</h5>
      </div>
      <div className={content}>{children}</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally understand what you mean, I think this is the answer:

```
const questionColor = (questionIndex, activeQuestion) => {
    if (activeQuestion !== null && activeQuestion !== questionIndex) {
      return "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)";
    } else return "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  };
```

Working solution here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hellman-fxrmc

Comment: I wish I had a visual for this. But I edited the requirement in my original question -

So if I open question 2, it becomes the "current item" and the opacity of question 2 and its answer should be 100% and all others(question1 an question3) should dim out or turn 50% opacity.

I am able to do the opposite where the currently open item has a different style using the code you mentioned but this is the opposite - I want all other inactive items to dim while the current/active item is darker so it looks like its "selected"

Comment: Would this help you?
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hellman-fxrmc

Comment: thank you but I got this to work. Now imagine when one of the questions is highlighted, (green in your example) the other questions turn dim so the green looks bright and pops out. Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean with pop out? Changing position or only visual effect?

Comment: Only visual effect. If a question is in the Open state, questions in the Closed state will be faded.

Comment: Like this one? https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hellman-fxrmc You can add whatever style to the style in line 19. Or even better, you can create css stylesheet and use them, see second set of questions.

Comment: Thank you for spending time on this and trying to make sense of what i'm trying to achieve without a visual example!

I'm trying again with words, please bear with me- 
Imagine if all the questions are black color when none of the questions are selected. Lets call it static state or something where everything looks same, color of text is black. Now when one of the questions is clicked, the clicked question remains color black but other questions which were in "static state" fade.